# Apply application.groovy in GORM standalone

Tags: java, groovy, grails-orm

In my script I'm using

```
implementation 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate5:8.0.1'
```

and initialize the domain classes with

```
Map config = new YamlSlurper().parse( getClass().getResourceAsStream( '/application.yml' ) )
new HibernateDatastore( config.gorm, classes as Class[] )
```

Now I want to provide some default values to each Entity's mapping [as per ref-doc](https://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#_the_default_mapping_constraints) by adding the code to `src/main/resources/application.groovy`:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
  id column:'o_id'
  version column:'chng_id'
  lastUpdated column:'upd'
}
```

The file is ignored though, and no default mappings are applied.

What is the proper way to apply the default mappings in a GORM standalone setup?

Comment: @jeff-scott-brown can you have a look please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following setup:, putting the GORM default mapping into the initializer class:

```
static MAPPING = {
  id column:'o_id'
  version 'ch_id'
  lastUpdated column:'upd'
}

Map config = (Map)new YamlSlurper().parse( getClass().getResourceAsStream( '/application.yml' ) )

config.gorm[ 'grails.gorm.default.mapping' ] = MAPPING // <- custom mapping injection

new HibernateDatastore( config.gorm, classes as Class[] )
```

and

`application.yml`

```
gorm:
  dataSource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:c:/db/demo-db
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
  hibernate:
    hbm2ddl.auto: update
```

The only gotcha here is, that in none of the domain classes the fields from `MAPPING` must be present!